# How to do classification manually parsing the support vectors from LibSVM model?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

As much as I understand, I could parse the support vectors from the model produced by training with a set of data with LibSVM.

What would be the formula, to produce the classifier?

Do I need the data in the headers of the file, like the following (kernel etc...before the listed support vectors):

```
 svm_type c_svc
 kernel_type rbf
 gamma 0.125
 nr_class 4
 total_sv 1038
 rho -0.859244 -0.876628 -0.958343 0.543365 -1.10722 -1.79433
 label 2 1 3 0
 nr_sv 364 276 242 156
 SV
```

My case is

- I want to do classification from Node.JS. But there isn't any bindings for LibSVM for it, yet.
- Since my models are not going to change, I would like to do the classification in Node.JS, holding the model in-memory.
- If this proves to be slow, I rather write the same classification from scratch in C++ and create a wrapper module if it's only a matter of a simple computation (as I suspect it is).

Thanks.

Comment: If you are still interessed to use libsvm on node, there is library  called [node-svm](https://github.com/nicolaspanel/node-svm)

Comment: Thanks, I've rewritten the classification in JavaScript from the libsvm's source, but haven't released that. This should be better for people that are ok with a binary dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to translate the C function to Javascript.

Here is the relevant code:

```
double svm_predict_values(const svm_model *model, const svm_node *x, double* dec_values)
{
        int i;
        int nr_class = model->nr_class;
        int l = model->l;

        double *kvalue = Malloc(double,l);
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
                kvalue[i] = Kernel::k_function(x,model->SV[i],model->param);

        int *start = Malloc(int,nr_class);
        start[0] = 0;
        for(i=1;i<nr_class;i++)
                start[i] = start[i-1]+model->nSV[i-1];

        int *vote = Malloc(int,nr_class);
        for(i=0;i<nr_class;i++)
                vote[i] = 0;

        int p=0;
        for(i=0;i<nr_class;i++)
                for(int j=i+1;j<nr_class;j++)
                {
                        double sum = 0;
                        int si = start[i];
                        int sj = start[j];
                        int ci = model->nSV[i];
                        int cj = model->nSV[j];

                        int k;
                        double *coef1 = model->sv_coef[j-1];
                        double *coef2 = model->sv_coef[i];
                        for(k=0;k<ci;k++)
                                sum += coef1[si+k] * kvalue[si+k];
                        for(k=0;k<cj;k++)
                                sum += coef2[sj+k] * kvalue[sj+k];
                        sum -= model->rho[p];
                        dec_values[p] = sum;

                        if(dec_values[p] > 0)
                                ++vote[i];
                        else
                                ++vote[j];
                        p++;
                }

        int vote_max_idx = 0;
        for(i=1;i<nr_class;i++)
                if(vote[i] > vote[vote_max_idx])
                        vote_max_idx = i;

        free(kvalue);
        free(start);
        free(vote);
        return model->label[vote_max_idx];
}
```

Notice that you have to recreate this equation:

[image]

The only difference is since your model has 4 classes, you need to implement the vote system which is basically the code above.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Pedrom. Is your answer missing the equation you mention? As for the code above - you have stripped this function from LibSVM's source: https://github.com/arnaudsj/libsvm/blob/master/svm.cpp#L2459 Nice. :)

Comment: Oops... for some reason it didn't show up... now is fixed :) And yeah... just removed the parts that could make some noise, it is a shame that your model is not binary because it could be even easier.